# iOS MobileVLCKit and VideoCore conflict

Tags: ios, vlc, rtmp

I'm using MobileVLCKit to stream video and audio from Wowza RTMP server. At the same time I'm using VideoCore][1](https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore) to stream audio to Wowza RTMP server (I closed off the video channel in VideoCore). Now I'm attempting to make this sort of a teleconferencing solution. Now I'm limited to RTMP or RTSP, not teleconferencing solution (WebRTC or SIP or what not...I am not familiar with these at the moment) because of the limitation on the other end of the line.

The above setup doesn't work. Turning the both functions (video and audio streaming down and audio streaming up) individually runs fine. But not when run simultaneously as audio cannot be heard on the other end. In fact, when app started with VideoCore streaming audio upstream, as soon as I started to downstream via MobileVLCKit, audio cannot be heard on the other end, even though the stream is open. It appears that microphone is somehow wrested away from VideoCore, even though MobileVLC should not need the microphone.

However, when I made the two into two apps and allow them to run in the background (audio & airplay background mode), the two runs fine with one app stream down video & audio and the other picking up microphone voices and stream to the other end.

Is there any reason why the two functions appear to apparently be in conflict within the same app, and any ideas how to resolve the conflict?

Comment: are you still using MobileVLCKit with Wowza? I'm doing the same and would love to chat with you.

Comment: @user3344977 Someone else was setting up Wowza. And I did use MobileVLCKit successfully except the above situation. We put on hold to this video thing and is using another commercial solution instead. We'll be dealing with videos later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. Say I have two objects, a vlc player and the other audio processor which listens the microphone. It works fine in simulator for operating both functions in the same time. But conflict in the iPhone device. I think the root cause is that there is only one position or right for listening the microphone. And vlc occupies the right so that my audio processor cannot work. But for some reasons, I cannot modify the vlc code. So I'd to figure out the workaround resolution. And I found one.

The problem comes from vlc which occupies the right but doesn't event use the microphone, and my audio processor did. So the way appears clearly. That is, vlc player plays first and then we new the other object instance, audio processor in my case, which needs to listen the microphone. Since audio processor comes after vlc player, it takes back the right of microphone listening. And they both work properly.

For your reference and hope it can help you.